# I have created a search bar in java. But it has some errors

Tags: java

```
    try {

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        String qry = "SELECT * FOME users WHERE id=?";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(qry);
        pst.setString(1, txtSearch.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        tblEmployee.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //Show what is the catched error

    }
```

`rs = pst.executeQuery();` doesn't work and throws following  error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOME users
>   WHERE id='df'' at line 1

Comment: FOME? Maybe you meant FROM?

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have believed the error. `FOME` should be `FROM`,

```
String qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a type in SQL statement. It should be

```
String qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?";
```

Notice the typo, `FOME`.

Whenever you get exceptions like these, first execute the query using SQL client before doing it through Java.

Comment: Yp I got it Thanks